# Using host's native SMTP to send emails alongside Google Apps

Tags: smtp, cpanel, google-apps

### Current Setup

I use **Google Apps** for personal / non-transactional emails. MX records for my domain point to google.

I have a dedicated IP for my LAMP server, and the SMTP port is available. I use cPanel to manage the server. I have created an email account through cPanel.

### Goal

I want to use my **host's native SMTP** for sending transactional emails. I cannot use Google Apps SMTP because of per-day limit. These transactional emails need neither be saved in sent items nor replies to such emails be monitored.

### Problem Area

I am not able to send transactional mails using host's native SMTP (not able to set this up, so no errors yet!)

- Q1. Is the goal (using both host's native SMTP and Google Apps)
  achievable? Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351297/can-i-use-google-apps-for-domain-email-and-still-use-a-sendmail-server-to-send) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462440/iis-smtp-server-installed-on-local-server-in-parallel-to-google-apps), I believe it should be.
- Q2. If yes, how should I setup in my cPanel? Please let me know if more [relevant] information about server setup is required to answer this.

Answer (score -1):

Q1: Yes.

Q2: Same as if you were setting it up without Google Apps. Sending mail does not require any special setup. If you are still having difficulty, you need to check with your provider or ask the question of a cpanel expert -- the problem is unrelated to Google Apps.

**What you didn't ask but need to know:**

[Cannot deliver email to Google Apps address; Gmail receives the same email fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143200/cannot-deliver-email-to-google-apps-address-gmail-receives-the-same-email-fine/15158808#15158808)

[Why can't my server send outgoing email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525113/why-cant-my-server-send-outgoing-email/16528010#16528010)

Comment: Hi Weehooey, you didn't provide an answer to Q2.

Comment: Mohamed, I am not a cPanel expert. I provided the information regarding the Google Apps. I would assume the cPanel documentation has everything Vishal might need to know. The substance was would this work and are there any relevant issues when doing in parallel with cPanel -- which I did.